# Abstractly constructing splitting fields

Tags: field-theory

I have a series of exercises where I have to determine the degree of various splitting fields. I am freely using the following observation, which I feel is intuitively true, but I am asking here to make sure it's true.

> Let $f(x) \in \mathbb Q[x]$. Let $a_1,\dots,a_n$ be roots of $f$ in $\mathbb C$. Then the splitting field is $\mathbb Q(a_1,\dots,a_n)$.

Clearly $f$ splits over this extension, but I'm not sure how to "rigorously" check that this is indeed the smallest extension.

Comment: This true by definition. $\mathbb Q(a_1, \dotsc, a_n)$ is the smallest subfield of $\mathbb C$, which contains $a_1, \dotsc, a_n$, hence in which $f$ splits.

Answer (score 1):

It's by definition. Recheck your definition of what $\mathbb{Q}(a)$ means! It's already the smallest such field.

Comment: Thanks! Another quick q if you don't mind: If someone says E is a splitting field over F, are they implicitly implying there is some polynomial with coefficients in F that splits in E?

Comment: They are /explicitly stating/ it. "$E$ is a splitting field over $F$" means that there is some polynomial $f\in F[x]$ such that $E$ is the splitting field of $F$

Answer (score -2):

The proposed minimal spliff (splitting field) is indeed minimal because it by definition is the minimal extension of the rationals which contains the roots.

Comment: Apart from the fact, that it is not clear what you mean by "independent" (We always have $\sum a_i \in \mathbb Q$), it does not even matter. Of course it might be true that for instance $\mathbb Q(a_1, \dotsc, a_n)=\mathbb Q(a_1,a_2)$ holds, but that does not change the fact, that $\mathbb Q(a_1, \dotsc, a_n)$ is the splitting field. Always.